# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore - AWS Lambda - XML Documentation

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle.ASPNetcore 3.0.0.  My Webapi is in .net core 2.0.  When I enable the XML documentation feature, both in the project properties and the (2) lines in the startup.cs file, it works fine locally.  When I publish to AWS Lambda I get a "interal server error", I have a feeling it has something to do with the .xml file location.  I am not sure if it is trying to write that file in the lambda or if that file is static and pushed with the code, when I publish.  I would like to use the extra /// information to further enhance the basic swagger doc that gets created without the XML documentation.  Can anyone offer up an advise here?

Comment: Your feeling is correct, the location of the file is the problem, I ran into the same in Azure

Comment: ...and Yes by default that file is static and pushed with the code when we publish